# iPad (4th generation) Wi-Fi + Cellular (MM) background mode not working

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have an app working properly in background mode in my iPhone 4 and iPhone 5. I also tested it in xcode simulator (iOS 9.1). In background mode, I'm receiving location notifications and I push them to server. However, I'm now testing it on an `iPad (4th generation) Wi-Fi + Cellular (MM) A1460` and when the app enters in background mode it stops receiving notifications and sending requests to my server.

Any idea why the app it's not working in background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by setting

locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;